# Beginner weight loss healthy?

Tags: weight-gain

I'm 26 male weighing 65Kgs and I have been working out for the last couple of months and I ate little over my maintenance calories. In this duration I have taken body composition analysis and turns out I have gained ~700 gms of muscle and lost ~3kgs of fat in 45 days. Is this normal and healthy considering this is the first time working out ?

Comment: I think it may help if you specified what you were before. You weigh 65kg now, what were you before? What was your body type before? A little overweight? A beanpole?  I ask because I've been working out for about the same amount of time but I've allegedly lost 5kg of fat (according to body impedance measurements) but I started out obese so I have a lot to lose. Great job on your progress though! It could be healthy since up to ~1kg loss a week is considered "healthy" weightloss, but beginners tend to lose more at first, I believe.

Comment: Also, welcome to Physical Fitness.SE!

Comment: Thanks, I was some where between 67-68 kgs and skinny fat